# how to make a "`" symbol in a string in ahk?

Tags: string, autohotkey

I am trying to make this string

```
string := " %%i IN (`"
```

but if i try and test i with msgbox it doesn't make the "`" symbol

```
msgbox,%line33%
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escape your symbol (backtick) by prefixing it with a backtick (which happens to be the default escape character):

```
string := " %%i IN (``"
```

Refer to [#EscapeChar](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/_EscapeChar.htm) for details.

Comment: The backtick (`) is a special character in AHK. It's the default escape character. Two consecutive escape characters (``) result in a single literal character. http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/_EscapeChar.htm